# How to change default location of Thunderbird cache directory?

Tags: thunderbird, home-directory, cache

Mozilla Firefox has the key `browser.cache.parent_directory` for this but in Thunderbird I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try adding the option yourself?

After you open the config editor (`Edit` --> `Preferences` --> `Advanced`--> Make sure you are in the `General` tab --> `Config Editor`), right click inside the new window.

In the context menu, choose `New` to open a submenu and click on `String`.

You will be asked to enter the preference name, put in `browser.cache.disk.parent_directory` and click Ok. Next you will be asked to enter the value, which is the path you wish to use to store the cache.

It will create a directory called `Cache` inside the path you provide in the option, where it will store the cache files.

P.S. It is `browser.cache.disk.parent_directory` and not `browser.cache.parent_directory`

Comment: Thanks @Dan! Works! Previously I didn't know where I can find the property browser.cache.disk.parent_directory.

Answer (score 2):

In Version 24 of Thunderbird you get to the configuration menu by:
...Tools > options > Advanced > General > Config Editor
Then everything is the same as above.